# Use Enum values as a key in interface

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to create an interface that uses values from an Enum.

```
enum TestEnum {
  'VAL1' = 'TEST1',
  'VAL2' = 'TEST2'
}

interface IMyInterface {
  [TestEnum[key in TestEnum]]: {
    // some code
  }
}

const objToType: IMyInterface = {
  TEST1: { / ** \ }
  TEST2: { / ** \ }
}
```

It throws an error

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression
> whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusing bit is that `[key in TestEnum]` returns the "values" of the enum rather than the "keys" (if you want to iterate the keys you'd use `[key in keyof TestEnum]`).

This is easy to do using a `type` declaration rather than an interface declaration:

```
enum TestEnum {
  'VAL1' = 'TEST1',
  'VAL2' = 'TEST2'
}

type IMyInterface = {
  [key in TestEnum]: { /* */ }
}

const objToType: IMyInterface = {
  TEST1: { },
  TEST2: { }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAUFKByAagIIAyAjLlALx4zIDKM5ANNnkcQEwXW60NeYAvpkyIAngAdgUAJIBZMTJCJgAJwBmAQwDG06lhwBtANbAxUAJYhYCFGgC6ALijooAegBUUD26jDhmNoA9iBIUEEARgBWMEEwksDO8orKalq6VC6sfIzOroIsODkceX5CmEA)